# turn char into unsigned ints while preserving their absolute value

Tags: c

So I need to turn the first 5 letters of a word into an unsigned int that keeps their relative value in the alphabet, such as that "fabulous" becomes 5 0 1 20 11 or 5012011 to then be able to use it as a key in a trie.

right now i have:

```
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    unsigned int output = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        int multiplier = 10000;
        if (i > 0)
        {
            multiplier = 10000 / (i * pow(10.0, i-1) / i);
        }
        output += (toupper(word[i]) - 'A') * multiplier;
    }
    return output;
}
```

now it outputs 50311 which is the correct sum of all the ints * their respective place (the 5 * 10,000 for being in the first place of 5 and so on) but any number over 10 "bleeds through" the previous value, so 20 which is the U bleeds through and affects the b, and the 11 affects the last digit of the 20, but the same it would happen with every letter that happens to be after the J.

I also thought of adding each value to an array so output[0] = 5 and so on, but then i need to convert the array into an unsigned int to return it and have no clue how to go about doing that.

Comment: I am fairly confident that the algorithm you are trying to implement is broken and would contain ambiguities if you succeeded in implementing it. (presuming you are talking about "key in a trie" rather than a hash. Two different things here.)

Comment: caaaa = 20000 and uaaaa = 20000

Comment: @IłyaBursov  Good catch, maybe not use this as a basis for your homegrown crypto project ; -)

Comment: OK, learn how to debug, it's most valuable, not meaning that in a snarky way.  Also, as an alternative algo, you could cat the `5 0 1 20 11` values as string operations, then convert back to int as the final step, in case a different set of logic steps becomes useful.

Comment: @AviBerger yes, its the first part of a larger algorithm im trying to get at, so indeed this would not be necessarily a hash, its just something im working on.

Comment: @ChrisO no snark taken i know i have a ton to learn still, but in this case i know where the bug is, it was adding the 20*10 to the 1*100 leading to overlap and ambiguity and i was out of ideas, thanks!

Comment: @AviBerger I need to create a spellchecker for CS50, and my idea was to basically create a hash table using a trie at first to reduce collisions. break every word into its 5 first letters and a remainder if it has any, then, use a trie to get ever word <= to 5 characters. that would get me to check most words in constant time without doing thousands of checks on a linked list.
To check a word, get the first 5 letters into numbers, go through the trie and find the end, if you reach the 5th letter, check for any remainder to be equal between the linked list at end of the trie and the remainder

Comment: For a top level trie, your original version could have different strings mapping to the same entry as in @IłyaBursov's example. That's what I was commenting on. Barmar's answer would deal with this issue and require a 32 bit key. A simple bit packing scheme would take a 25 bit key. A base 26 style approach would only reduce that to 24 bits. Different algorithms to create the key, different memory footprint for the trie itself. I'd consider the other approaches for the potential memory savings. (Gigabytes)

Comment: Not sure how the memory usage will actually pan out, that depends on how you are actually setting this up and what the distribution is. If you are going through a trie on the first 5 letters and then dropping to a hash or linked list, I don't think you actually want the first 5 chars into a single int value. I seem to be busy being confused here. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Make each character use 2 digits in the result, then there won't be any overlap between each letter's digits. Do this by using powers of 100 rather than 10. The result for your example will be `500012011`.

```
#define LIMIT 5

unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    unsigned int output = 0;
    size_t len = strlen(word);
    int max = len < LIMIT ? len : LIMIT;
    unsigned int multiplier = 100000000;
    for(int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        output += (toupper(word[i]) - 'A') * multiplier;
        multiplier /= 100;
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: I was going to propose using five bits per character, since 5 × 5 = 25 < 32.  I was about to say, with two digits, you'll blow that out!  But no, 2525252525 does still fit.

Comment: I was originally worried, but since it's unsigned you can go up to 4e10

Answer (score 2):

OP: "*...but then i need to convert the array into an unsigned int to return it and have no clue how to go about doing that.*"

It's not hard. With some bit masking (low order 5 bits) and shifting (20, 15, 10, 5, 0), one can quickly assemble an integer value. 5x5=25 bits, so 'signed/unsigned' in 32 bits is irrelevant.

```
uint32_t hash( const char *word ) {
    const int LTRS_USED = 5;

    uint32_t val = 0;
    int shft = LTRS_USED * 5;
    for( size_t c = 0; c < LTRS_USED && word[c]; c++ )
        val |= (word[c] & 037) << (shft -= 5); // see disclaimer below

    return val;
}

int main() {
    const char *words[] = {
        "The", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "jumped", "over", "a", "lazy", "dog"
    };
    const size_t nw = sizeof words/sizeof words[0];

    for( size_t i = 0; i < nw; i++ )
        printf( "%10d %s\n", hash( words[i] ), words[i] );

    return 0;
}
```

Notice that the values below (particularly "jumps/jumped") show that the integer values indicate achieving a "sorted" hash sequence. (If 'e' was mapped to 17, 's' would be 31. It works.)

```
  21238784 The
  18523243 quick
   2703086 brown
   6807552 fox
  11187731 jumps
  11187717 jumped
  16455232 over
   1048576 a
  12643104 lazy
   4692992 dog
```

One could experiment with using 4 letters or 6 to see how that affects the speed and volume requirements.

**(disclaimer: This answer is predicated that all characters are 7 bit ASCII. Other character sets will require other solutions.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake with `multiplier`

Try this one:

```
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    unsigned int output = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        int charVal = toupper(word[i]) - 'A';
        if (charVal > 9)
        {
            output = output * 100 + charVal;
        }
        else
        {
            output = output * 10 + charVal;
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```